# Named anchor link from other page jumps to top

Tags: php, jquery, anchor

My client asked me to put one section of their one-page site on a separate landing page (http://princetongyn.com/relieve-dryness.php) and then include navigation back to the main site (http://princetongyn.com/index.php). (Please note that this site is for a gynecologist and related services.) The one page site uses IDs as named anchors for navigation (#services, #providers, etc.). So, I changed the primary navigation on the landing page to index.php#services and so forth.

Here's the problem: when I click on such a link back to a section of the home page from the landing page, the page initially loads in the approapriate section and then - after a second or two - jumps to the top of the page and the move to the section is lost.

I've tried including a jQuery routine to preventDefault on both the landing and home page:

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But I still issue remains. Any thoughts on what else it might be?

Comment: could you post the markup as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following jQuery which is causing this:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: (Hand slapping head) Thanks. Can't believe I missed that.